# How to tweet an image

Tags: twitter, addthis

I am using addthis toolbar in my website,

And when I click tweet on it, it shares a link of the image I am looking at.

I want to tweet the image itself,
The image is dynamic - not a static one

and i've put a meta tag in the head of the page

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Daily Puzzle 08/24/2014 | Chess Puzzle 144 | NA - Zukertort, London 1872 | TheRookBook.com" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<p>Zokertort wins by a wonderful sacrifice and a sequence of right check moves.</p>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.therookbook.com/images/viewboard.png?id=144"/> <----this
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.therookbook.com/viewboard.jsp?id=144"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
```

is this possible ?

Comment: The short answer is "yes, it's possible".  You haven't included enough information in your post for anyone to answer helpfully.  What language are you working in?  What have you already tried?  Do you have code that's not working?  Providing this information will get you helpful answers.

Comment: I am using javascript. I read their manual and it said i need to include meta tags for it to work, i showed you my meta tags. The content of the image is dynamic and is generated by a jsp file. But when i try to tweet the image,  i end up tweeting the link instead.

Comment: In order to be able to help you identify the problem in the code, we'll need to see the code.